# iText7 Custom Timestamp

Tags: java, pdf, timestamp, itext

I am trying to add a timestamp from a custom server to a PDF signature and getting an error. The following code is the signature.

```
Timestamper ts = new Timestamper(new URL(ts_url), ts_user, ts_pass, new BouncyCastleDigest().getMessageDigest("SHA-256"));  
signer.signDetached(new BouncyCastleDigest(), pks, chain, null, null, new Timestamper(new URL(ts_url), ts_user, ts_pass, new BouncyCastleDigest().getMessageDigest("SHA-256")), 0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CADES);
```

This code works properly if I dont add a Timestamp and sign using the computer clock. I implemented the Interface to use my TSA provider and get an errror.

The Interface implementation:

```
class Timestamper implements ITSAClient{
    private final URL url;
    private final String username;
    private final String password;
    private final MessageDigest digest;
 
    Timestamper(URL url, String username, String password, MessageDigest digest) {
        this.url = url;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.digest = digest;
    }

    @Override
    public MessageDigest getMessageDigest() throws GeneralSecurityException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.digest;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getTimeStampToken(byte[] arg0) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.digest.reset();
        byte[] hash = this.digest.digest(arg0);
         
        // generate cryptographic nonce
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        int nonce = random.nextInt();
         
        // generate TSA request
        TimeStampRequestGenerator tsaGenerator = new TimeStampRequestGenerator();
        tsaGenerator.setCertReq(true);
        ASN1ObjectIdentifier oid = new ASN1ObjectIdentifier(NISTObjectIdentifiers.id_sha256.getId());
        TimeStampRequest request = tsaGenerator.generate(oid, hash, BigInteger.valueOf(nonce));
         
        // get TSA response
        byte[] tsaResponse = getTSAResponse(request.getEncoded());
        
        System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(tsaResponse));

        TimeStampResponse response = new TimeStampResponse(tsaResponse);
        response.validate(request);
         
        TimeStampToken token = response.getTimeStampToken();
        if (token == null) {
            throw new IOException("Response does not have a time stamp token");
        }
         
        return token.getEncoded();
    }
    
    private byte[] getTSAResponse(byte[] request) throws IOException {
        URLConnection connection = this.url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/timestamp-query");
        connection.setRequestProperty(this.username, this.password);
        

        // read response
        OutputStream output = null;
        try {
            output = connection.getOutputStream();
            output.write(request);
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(output);
        }

        InputStream input = null;
        byte[] response;
        try {
            input = connection.getInputStream();
            response = IOUtils.toByteArray(input);
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(input);
        }

            return response;
        }

    @Override
    public int getTokenSizeEstimate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Custom Provider timestamp size: 2576 - 2577 returning 2580
        return 2580;
    }
```

The error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSSignedHelper, method: <clinit> signature: ()V) Incompatible argument to function
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedData.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tsp.TimeStampToken.getSignedData(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tsp.TimeStampToken.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tsp.TimeStampResponse.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tsp.TimeStampResponse.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tsp.TimeStampResponse.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.xxx.main.Timestamper.getTimeStampToken(SignatureHandler.java:301)
    at com.itextpdf.signatures.PdfPKCS7.getEncodedPKCS7(PdfPKCS7.java:900)
    at com.itextpdf.signatures.PdfSigner.signDetached(PdfSigner.java:648)
    at com.itextpdf.signatures.PdfSigner.signDetached(PdfSigner.java:538)
    at com.xxx.main.SignatureHandler.sign(SignatureHandler.java:239)
    at com.xxx.main.Main.main(Main.java:81)
```

I have been struggling for a week now, I've used iText 7.1.7 and 7.1.14 and get same results.

Comment: Forgot to add: I do get a proper timestamp response.

Comment: This is the base64 for one of the received timestamps: https://pastefs.com/pid/272194

Comment: It looks like a dependency issue, which bc artifact versions do you use? `org.bouncycastle.tsp.*` and `org.bouncycastle.cms.*` appear to be in mismatch.

Comment: aparently im a moron.. this was the issue, never remembered to update BC :facepalm: Thanks @mkl